# Transform number of seconds to humanized string in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a number of seconds (for example 123 sec).

And I need to transform that seconds to humanized string like:

```
2 minutes 3 seconds
```

How can I do it with plain Moment.js without any external plugins?
I tried to do it with that code:

```
let test = document.querySelector('#test')
let time = moment.duration(123, 'seconds')

 test.innerHTML = `
    ${moment.duration(time.minutes(), 'minutes').humanize()}
    ${moment.duration(time.seconds(), 'seconds').humanize()}
`
```

But the output is:

```
2 minutes a few seconds
```

P.S That would be great if there will be used Moment's locales for easy switch to another language.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it with plain Moment.js without any external plugins?

Why?

You're already using Moment itself... You can use the [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin and so easily get exactly what you want.

```
moment.duration(123, 'seconds').format("m [minutes] s [seconds]");
// "2 minutes 3 seconds"
```

Or [auto-localize](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#auto-localized-unit-labels) it...

```
moment.duration(123, 'seconds').format("m __ s __");
```

Comment: OK, but I can't figure out how to set different language to mins and secs.

Comment: You'll want to read this:
https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#localization
and this:
https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#extending-moments-locale-object

You need to extend Moment's locale object for whatever moment locale you are using.